# Linking to stylesheet in root directory

Tags: css

I am having a major issue trying to link to a stylesheet which is my root directory. I am connecting to it from a HTML file which is in a subdirectory of the root directory.

I would think this code would work (seeing as / means root directory)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

However, it does not. Because the subdirectory is also only one folder down from the root directory, I also tried:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
```

this also does not work.

Comment: The first example should work. Checked the console for errors?

Comment: If both don't work, a more exact map of the file structure would be helpful. The only other thing I can think of is an access rights problem.

Comment: I haven't checked the console for errors. I'm still fairly new to running a website, how could I go about that? My web host has an "IIS Administration Console", would that be it?

Comment: @user3227878 no, check the console in your browser. see if ou are getting a 404 error or 500 error on the get request for that css page.

Comment: It does not look like there are any errors on the page. I am baffled as to why this is not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

Your first code line should work as "/" really means root :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

This will find the file https://MY_DOMAIN/style.css

Are you sure that your file style.css is at the root of your project and not in another folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try

```
<style>
    @import url('/style.css');
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works. For whatever reason, I could not link back to the root directory. I am still completely baffled about that, however, I did find a way to make it work.

I did it with this code:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://engagearcade.com/style.css" />
</head>
```